# -l: option via Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, linker

When I write lib names in properties in Eclipce it uses -l option, that is replaced by if we wrote *-lsomelib* to *-l:libsomelib.a*. How can I manage to use -l: option, bacause I don't want lib-prefix be added to the file name and I want to link *.lib file

Comment: Are you working on Unix/Linux/etc.?  If so, the convention is that names of libraries are prefixed with `lib`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mention that - I work on Windows

Comment: What tool chain have you selected to do the compilation/linking?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, GCC static libraries use the form `lib<name>.a`, hence why the -l arguments are being translated as such. If you wish to override this behaviour, use the full file name of the library to link against, e.g. `gcc main.c mylibrary.a`.